# Issue adding a new field to an entity in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am running into an issue when adding a new field to an entity. In my entity I had 526 fields, I tried to add a new one but I got the error message "Attribute xxx cannot be created because we have hit a maximum number of attributes allowed for an entity (1000)". However I only have 526 fields in the entity. Furthermore, I deleted one field I don't need anymore and I tried to add my new field but I still have the same error message even though I've deleted one field. Could anyone help me out please. I do appreciate it. Thanks !

Walloud

Comment: Are you on-premises or on-line? I'm taking it from the tag you are online but would like to confirm. If on-premises, what version of SQL are you running? Have you tried importing the solution to localized dev environment, for example in VM, to see if you can recreate the issue?

Comment: What are you doing that required 526 attributes on an entity?

Comment: @Nickow: We're on-premise and we're using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Daryl: I'm not the one who created all these fields but I'm the one who has to resolve the issue. Have you ever used the project called "CRM Data Detective"? They say it helps to find out which fields aren't used,I installed it but it doesn't load my entities :(

Comment: Nope, never used it.  With it being a CodePlex project, I'm guessing that they've never tested entities with 526 attributes before and there GUI is crying "uncle".

Answer (score 1):

You will be hitting the column limit, even with only 526 fields.

You have to remember that CRM will add its own fields in addition to the ones that you have, such as ones for base currency. This can take you over the limit.

Also consider that the Filtered Views that CRM automatically creates have extra columns for lookup (name), optionset (name) and date (local) fields which can also mean you exceed the limit there.

I think your only options are to delete more fields in order to free up the room, or re-architect your entity design to split it over multiple related entities instead

Comment: Thank you William. I found a project called "CRM Data Detective", do you know it? I installed the solution but when I launch it it doesn't load any entity ! I googled it but no one seems to have the issue. Do you have any idea please? Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing the SQL Server 8k row limit

you can check the field names and verify this.

more information here:

http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2013/09/dealing-with-8k-sql-server-row-limits.html

Comment: Thank you Guido. I found a project called "CRM Data Detective", do you know it? I installed the solution but when I launch it it doesn't load any entity ! I googled it but no one seems to have the issue. Do you have any idea please? Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that some fields, such as currency will have two separate fields in SQL thus increment the column count by two for each one you create. If you have 500+ fields on a single entity then it is time to normalize the data and start breaking it out into related entities. It will be better for performance and your data in the long run.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Travis. I found a project called "CRM Data Detective", do you know it? I installed the solution but when I launch it it doesn't load any entity ! I googled it but no one seems to have the issue. Do you have any idea please? Thank you again !

Comment: I suspect that if you have a large data-set (number of records/fields) it will take some time for it to load.